# Should I keep my laptop plugged in as much as possible?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging, lithium-ion

I know there's already some feeds on this but I just can't get one straight answer. Everybody says different things.  I have an Asus laptop with a Lithium-polymer.  I do game a lot so what's your opinion.  I want my battery life to last, so wouldn't keeping it plugged in as much as possible do this?  This would minimize the cycles, and I know my laptop cannot overcharge the battery as it only charges up to 97%.  I know overheating is the main factor and I will try to keep that under control.  I guess I have all the information but just want confirmation that keeping my laptop plugged in won't damage the battery.

Comment: If your computer allows it, remove the battery when it is about 40-50% charged and put it in a cool location.

Comment: I cannot take out the battery

Comment: I can understand the advice to take the battery out. But I'd leave it in. Works like a UPS that way. If there's a power outage your laptop keeps going instead of shutting off possibly corrupting things.

Comment: I can't take it out anyways. I just want to know if I can keep my laptop plugged in without the battery going bad

Answer (score 0):

The laptop knows how to take care of the battery. It will engage actual charging only when needed. Nothing bad will happen if you keep the adapter plugged in.

*DragonLord*'s advice is spot on if you want to preserve the battery as much as possible. Technically the best place for a Li-Ion battery to sit at is around 50% charge. But then what's the point. That's getting too OCD for me. The purpose of a battery is to make a laptop portable. It also serves as a kind of UPS, so that if there's a power outage, your laptop doesn't just shut off potentially corrupting data.

So go nuts, leave it plugged it to the wall, it's all good :-)